# Extracting frames with nvidia gpu

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gpu, google-colaboratory

I have over *500* videos and i need to extract frames every X seconds,
I wanted to use google colab to make use of the gpus to do the job as fast as possible, the frame must be in a lossless format, i thought about .png but ffmpeg kept failing with png format so im open to suggestion.
The video codecs is **"H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10"** and this is the command i tried to use:
`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -i "video231.mp4" -vf fps=1/2 -q:v 1 ./tests/%04d.png`

This one works, but colab keeps telling me I'm not using the gpus, i have tried others settings before but I get a format error.

Answer (score 0):

## Encoding

I am not aware of any lossless image format that is supported by hardware accelerated encoding.

## Decoding

You may be able to use hardware accelerated decoding. Examples from [FFmpeg Wiki: Hardware Acceleration - NVDEC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#NVDECCUVID).

Sample decode using CUDA/NVDEC:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i input.mp4 -vf fps=1/2 output-%04d.png
```

Sample H.264 decode using CUVID:

```
ffmpeg -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -vf fps=1/2 output-%04d.png
```

- Check the ​[GPU compatibility table](https://developer.nvidia.com/video-encode-and-decode-gpu-support-matrix-new) to see if your GPU can decode H.264.
- `-q:v 1` is ignored by PNG so I omitted it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, can you explain the difference between the 2 commands?

Comment: there is a typo error the output pattern 'output-%04.png' is incorrect, the correct form is 'output-%04d.png' , i.e. the letter 'd' is absent

Comment: this won't work at all, you need to hwdownload before you can output